Why Śiva is so vehemently denigrated as Sadā-aśiva etc. only in the Brahmakhanḍa of Garuḍa purāṇa and Śaivas are said to be destined for eternal hell?
In contrast, the Ācāra khaṇḍa, chapter 24 says worshippers of Sadāśiva will become free from death itself.

इच्छाज्ञानक्रियाशक्तिस्त्रिनेत्रो हि सदाशिवः ॥
एवं शिवार्च्चनध्यानी सर्वदा कालवर्जितः ॥५७৷৷


Sadāśiva is three-eyed. He has Icchā śakti, Jñānaśakti and Kriyāśakti. A person who worships Śiva like this and contemplates thus will be devoid of Kāla (become deathless).



Rudra (the Devataa born from VishveDevaas and who shot an arrow and beheaded Bramhaa) - associated with graveyards, turbulence, violence, pretas, bhutas and other negative entities is one thing.
He's rightfully called SadaaShiva (सदा अशिव -> सदाऽशिव -> सदाशिव). The meaning here is 'always inauspicious', which is naturally true.
Sadaashiva (सदा शिव -> सदाशिव)  with the triShakti and triNetra is Brahman/Ishwara. Adi Shakti is also said to have these three 'powers', when she's understood to be the highest power. The meaning in this case is 'always auspicious'.
While these names sound similar, that's only due to language/grammar rules, the meaning is the complete opposite.
These types of confusions are frequent, but do not make the mistake of confusing the triMurti with the triDevas. Trimurti are three and interconnected forms of Ishvara, they can be said to be one, and are said to be one in multiple places in multiple Puranas. The TriDevas on the other hand, primarily the issue is between Vishnu (of 12 Aadityas) and Rudra, are different entities who are Devataas, like Indra or Agni or Surya.
To make things extra confusing, Rudra with Maheshvara and Vishnu with Vishnu are associated partly too, due to the similarity in Guna. For example, Maheshwara in Kaala-Rudra-Agni Rupa facilitates Pralaya. In this sense, the Maheshwara (Ishvara's 1/3) is similar to Rudra as both have Guna of turbulence and destruction. The same applies to Vishnu (Ishvara) and 12 Aaditya Vishnu.
So, when it is said (in Puranas) that all other Devas like Rudra and (triDeva) Brahmaa depend on Vishnu(Ishvara). And, when that same text doesn't mention (12 Aaditya)Vishnu in the list of Devas who depend on (Ishvara) Vishnu, an alarming amount of people get confused and then assume that the triple part of Ishvara are in conflict with each other.
Steer clear of this major error.
You can think of it a bit like this, although it's not entirely accurate:
The colors represent a type of manifestation which is partially shared among Vishu and Vishnu, for example.


The common interpolation argument is really only entertained and proposed by people of limited understanding of this. "This doesn't make sense, instead of thinking about it or doing 5 minutes of research or asking someone who'd know, let me just say interpolation!". Although, it is true also that the Puranas do not make this too clear, but even then, there shouldn't be this much confusion. - To address another answer to this question.
*I'm using TriMurti and TriDeva as terms just for ease of conveying meaning, these terms are rarely if ever used in Puranas.

Interesting so are the 5 forms from Ishvara of Adishankaracharya the same as Ishvara, or different?

Also this sounds kind of like the trinity.

@Haridasa Yes, they would be the same. Just as the Vishnu aspect of Ishvara can be seen to be partially present in Vishnu Aaditya, other Devataas with higher or more complete manifestations can be understood to be the same. The Bramha-Vishnu-Shiva of Shrsthi-Sthiti and Samhaara is only one model (to which, Prajapati-Vishnu-Rudra correlate). All that exists, is within Ishvara, so any higher form can be said to be a "part" of him, including Ganesh or Surya or Shakti herself, and none are inferior to Prajapati-Vishnu or Rudra. It's just a different, less popular (yet completely valid) model.

Interesting can I learn more of this in scripture?

I'm not quire aware where you'll be able to get this understanding in a crystallized form. Afterall, there's a reason most people (a part of which is expressed in this question), seem to conflate disdain towards Rudra (which is present not just in Garuda Puraanam), as disdain towards Shiva. That reason being, that it's not very clear, especially if you're not aware of the structure of Devataas and their correlaries that are accessible within yourself. I can only recommend that you find a guru who has extensive knowledge of Puranas and Veda as a good solution to this. @Haridasa

Is their no more systematic way of looking at Ishvara I know Vishistadvaita and Dvaita have them in various places, but Advaita is unique in this case.

Like regarding scripture for these categories and distinctions.

@Haridasa The text Panchaadashi by Shri VidyaaRanya is extremely systematic in terms of divisions regarding Viraat, Antaryamin and others of Ishvara among other things. However, since it is an Advaita text, you will not find elaborate descriptions of how the connection between Ishvara and Devataas is established. Nevertheless, I'll recommend it if you want a more fundamental understanding (and if you can tolerate the torture, that is reading that book). You can add knowledge from Puranas on top of that to gain a pretty good understanding, over multiple years.

Will do sir!!!!!!

But I am first going to read Tattva Bodha & Atma Bodha As well as a list given by scholars.

Also sir I found this Manuscript with commentary of Panchadasi found here, https://openn.library.upenn.edu/Data/0002/html/mscoll390_item1056.html is this complete?
